# How to write a function that will return the output as an S3 Class

Tags: r, class, methods

I am new to R and I am having some difficulty understanding how to return the output of a S3 class for a function. I have some text and I need to write a summary method for it that will count the number of words in the text and the frequency of the top 3 words in the text. I have a function countwords that will count the words.  The text is above the code:

```
 text = 'The time of year was spring the sun shone for the birds who were not singing yet. The Local farmer was out in the fields preparing for the summer ahead. He had a spring in his step, for he was whistling.'

    #counts the number of words in the text
    countwords = function(x) {
      # Read in the words from the text and separate into a vector
      txt = unlist(strsplit(x,' '))
      # Loop through each word
      k = 0
      for(i in 1:length(txt)) {
        k = k + 1
      }

      return(k)
    }
    countwords(firstpar)
```

How do I return the output of this as an s3 class? How do I write a summary method/function? to count the words and also the top 3 words in the text? I am new to R and need some help explaining S3 classes and methods and functions. Is a function the same as a method?

Thank you

Comment: Put `class(k) <- c("yourclass", class(k))` before the `return` statement. You can then write S3 methods by simply giving them the name of the generic appanded with the class name, e.g., `summary.yourclass`.

Comment: Thank you. This probably sounds a bit simple but do I remove the return statement? return(k)...I have added the other code and called the method summary.countwords. How do i use this then generically? Is this still not just a function with a class added? Sorry for what are probably simple questions. I am new to this.

Comment: Study `help("class")`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do both things, which illustrates the way to add a class *and* not have to write all the methods you might need for that class. I've also tweaked your function a bit to be more efficient and to work on a vector of strings as inputs. You also don't need the `return()` call; IIRC it is slightly more efficient to not call `return` explicitly but to use the fact that R returns automatically the result of the final statement in the function.

```
mystring <- "The time of year was spring the sun shone for the birds who were not singing yet. The Local farmer was out in the fields preparing for the summer ahead. He had a spring in his step, for he was whistling."

# counts the number of words in the text
countwords <- function(x) {
  # Read in the words from the text and separate into a vector
  txt <- strsplit(x, " ")
  n <- sapply(txt, length)
  top3 <- lapply(txt, function(x) names(tail(sort(table(x)), 3)))
  out <- list(n = n, top3 = top3)
  class(out) <- c("mysummary", "list")
  out # implied that we return out here
}

countwords(mystring)
```

This gets us:

```
> countwords(mystring)
$n
[1] 41

$top3
$top3[[1]]
[1] "for" "was" "the"


attr(,"class")
[1] "mysummary" "list"
```

Which isn't pretty, but we can sort that later with a `print` method. Notice that this is just a list, hence I used `class(out) <- c("mysummary", "list")` as my S3 class(es) to indicate inheritance from class `"list"`

```
> str(countwords(mystring))
List of 2
 $ n   : int 41
 $ top3:List of 1
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "for" "was" "the"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "mysummary" "list"
```

That means we can subset it like any list without writing those methods:

```
> cw <- countwords(mystring)
> cw$n
[1] 41

> cw[[2]]
[[1]]
[1] "for" "was" "the"
```

That's all you really need for an S3 class. This doesn't change even if you stick this in a package. (What you need to do extra then relates to methods for ytou class and we don't have any of those as we inherit from class `"list"`

```
> inherits(cw, "list")
[1] TRUE
```

If you want to add a `print` method we can just do:

```
`print.mysummary` <- function(x, ...) {
  writeLines(strwrap("Number of words:", prefix = "\n"))
  print(x$n, ...)
  writeLines(strwrap("Top 3 Words:", prefix = "\n"))
  print(x$top3, ...)
  invisible(x) 
}
```

which then produces:

```
> cw

Number of words:
[1] 41

Top 3 Words:
[[1]]
[1] "for" "was" "the"
```

Answer (score 0):

To make @Roland's comments a little more explicit:

First, you'll create an S3 class of your own, let's call it `myTextClass`, and then assign the `class` attribute of your object `text`.

```
class(text)<-c('myTextClass')
```

At this point, the class `myTextClass` isn't doing much for us, so we need to make a method for this class. In particular, we'll make a new method for the `summary` function so that whenever `summary` encounters and object of class `myTextClass` it will execute our desired method instead of any others.

```
summary.myTextClass<-function(t){
    z1<- paste('Length of text is ', length(unlist(strsplit(t,' '))) ,sep=' ')

    tb<-table(unlist(strsplit(t,' ')))
    topWords<-paste(names(tb)[1:3],tb[1:3],sep=':')
    z2<- paste(c('Top words are... ', topWords) ,collapse=' ')

    return(c(z1,z2))
}
```

This method does some of the basic things you mention such as word counts and so on. Now when we call the generic function `summary` on an object of class `myTextClass`, this particular method will be called.

```
summary(text)
[1] "Length of text is  41"                  "Top words are...  a:1 ahead.:1 birds:1"
```